# Is it possible to use Google's API in an open source project?

Tags: android, open-source, licensing, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an android app which use some google's api (maps, places, translate).
My code is under Apache 2 License, but... is it in conflict with google's api ?

So, my question is, can I use Apache 2 License if my app use some Google's api ?

Thanks.

Yan.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no problem with using Google APIs, regardless of licence.

[Here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils) is one example of an open source project using Google maps.

Comment: Thanks, that's what i thought, but i was not completely sure.